# Generic Expression.Call for aggregate functions

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to adapt the code below to build generic function which returns expression for aggregate functions such as sum, count average, min, max for list of data

Sum is working but others are not. I have Additional information: Incorrect number of arguments exception. Yes, it is clear that is Expression.Call built incorrectly for others but can not find any doc how to build the right expression for other aggregate functions.

```
public Expression AggregateFunc(IQueryable source, string member, string aggFunc)
{
  // Properties
  PropertyInfo property = source.ElementType.GetProperty(member);
  FieldInfo field = source.ElementType.GetField(member);
  ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "f");
  Expression selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, (MemberInfo)property ?? field), parameter);            
  // Method
  var l = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == aggFunc).ToList();
  MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == aggFunc ); 
  return Expression.Call(
  null,
  method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { source.ElementType }),
  new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector) });
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<Int32FormFieldData>()
{
  new FormFieldData { Path = "1", Value = 1 },
  new FormFieldData { Path = "2", Value = 2 },
  new FormFieldData { Path = "3", Value = 3 }
};`
AggregateFunc(list.AsQueryable(), "Value", "Count");
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it work with Min, Max etc, you need to make some changes (see comments):

```
public static Expression AggregateFunc(IQueryable source, string member, string aggFunc) {
    PropertyInfo property = source.ElementType.GetProperty(member);
    FieldInfo field = source.ElementType.GetField(member);        
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "f");
    Expression selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, (MemberInfo) property ?? field), parameter);
    // Method
    // find correct method with two parameters: IQueryable and selector            
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(c => c.GetParameters().Length == 2).First(m => m.Name == aggFunc);
    // some aggregates have two generic type arguments (such as min, max, average)
    // others like Sum have just one
    var genArgs = new List<Type>();
    genArgs.Add(source.ElementType);
    if (method.GetGenericArguments().Length > 1) {
        genArgs.Add(property?.PropertyType ?? field.FieldType);
    }
    return Expression.Call(
        null,
        method.MakeGenericMethod(genArgs.ToArray()),
        new[] {source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector)});
}
```

However, Count is different because for it, selector does not make any sense (you don't call `Count(c => c.Value)`), so for that it's better to create separate method with different signature (without `member`).